# Calculate time differences between daylight saving time and non-daylight saving time

Tags: r, time, dst

I want to calculate time differences between daylight saving time and non-daylight saving time. But I do not know how to let R know that a time is daylight saving time or not.

For example, Phoenix do not adjust daylight saving time in the summer, whereas most areas in US do. If I wanna calculate the time differences in the following, it's supposed to be 3 hours rather than 2 hours. 
tzone = "America/Phoenix" will automatically set the time as "MST", which is a daylight saving time, but this is not what I want.

```
library(lubridate)
x <- "22/5/2016 23:50"
x <- dmy_hm(x)
x1 <- force_tz(x, tzone = "America/Phoenix")
x2 <- force_tz(x, tzone = "EST")

x1-x2
# The output is "Time difference of 2 hours". But actually it is supposed to be 3 hours.
```

I tried by setting tzone="EDT" or "MDT" to fix that. But it seems that R do not allow recognize those timezones.

```
> x2 <- force_tz(y, tzone = "EDT")
Warning messages:
1: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(lt) : unknown timezone 'EDT'
2: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(ct) : unknown timezone 'EDT'
> x3 <- force_tz(y, tzone = "MDT")
Warning messages:
1: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'EDT'
2: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(lt) : unknown timezone 'MDT'
3: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(ct) : unknown timezone 'MDT'
```

Comment: It is *three* hours in the *summer* not the winter.  See my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Dirk! Your code works. But what I mean in my code is a summer time. I put date in front of month. To clarify it, I modify the original date to 22/5/2016

Comment: Ahh. That is a common date format, but easy to mistake (in this part of the world, at least).  Best to stick to 2016-05-22.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem because of `EST`. From `?timezone`:

> Beware that some of these designations may not be what you expect: in
>   particular EST is a time zone used in Canada without daylight saving
>   time...

Use `US/Eastern` or `America/New_York` instead of `EST`. See `?OlsonNames()` for more information.

```
#DST
x1 = as.POSIXct("22/5/2016 23:50", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz = "America/New_York")
x2 = as.POSIXct("22/5/2016 23:50", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz = "America/Phoenix")
x2 - x1
#Time difference of 3 hours

#NOT DST
x1 = as.POSIXct("22/12/2016 23:50", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz = "America/New_York")
x2 = as.POSIXct("22/12/2016 23:50", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz = "America/Phoenix")
x2 - x1
#Time difference of 2 hours
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way. I use `anytime()` for convenience (from the [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package)

```
R> nyc <- format(anytime("12/05/2016 23:50", tz="America/New_York"))
R> phx <- format(anytime("12/05/2016 23:50", tz="America/Phoenix"))
R> diff(anytime(c(phx, nyc)))
Time difference of 2 hours
R>
```

You have to go through explicit textual representation (which is wasteful) as the underlying representation is always in UTC:

```
R> difftime(anytime("12/05/2016 23:50", tz="America/New_York"),
+           anytime("12/05/2016 23:50", tz="America/Phoenix"))
Time difference of 0 secs
R>
```

The desired / suspected *three* hour difference occurs only in the summer.  Using July instead of December:

```
R> phx <- format(anytime("07/05/2016 23:50", tz="America/Phoenix"))
R> nyc <- format(anytime("07/05/2016 23:50", tz="America/New_York"))
R> diff(anytime(c(phx, nyc)))
Time difference of 3 hours
R>
```

And of course, all that is done here with `anytime()` can be done with Base R functions.  This is just a shortcut, and it all comes down to how `POSIXt` handles this.

*Edit:*  I forgot that I have another helper in another package:

```
R> RcppCCTZ::tzDiff("America/Phoenix", "America/New_York", anytime("2016-05-22"))
[1] 3
R>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "S" in MST and EST stands for "standard." That's always the non-daylight savings version. You want to use EDT for eastern daylight time.

Comment: But R does not recognize timezones such as "EDT".

Comment: "EST5EDT" perhaps. "Eastern Time" is famously ambiguous since the Aussies have their own "Eastern" zone. (And "Americans" are famously insular in their assumptions.)